# Desencriptar o descifrar registro en SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-11g, tablas, encriptación

Tengo los siguientes datos en una de las columnas de mi tabla y se supone que está encriptado cada dato

```
1415131228
1415131215
1415914797
1415131174
1415131173
```

La cosa es que no sé que tipo de encriptamiento es, ni como desencriptarlo, la columna es tipo VARCHAR2 y lo que se supone que debo encontrar al desencriptarla es una **fecha** con hora incluida, pero no sé con que procedimiento, consulta o función obtener los datos que requiero.

Estoy trabajando SQL - PL/SQL - Tablas externas - Oracle 11g

Comment: ¿Podrías confirmar si esas fechas son, en realidad las siguientes fechas? 2014-11-04 21:00:28, 2014-11-04 21:00:15, 2014-11-13 22:39:57, 2014-11-04 20:59:34, 2014-11-04 20:59:33. Solo por la correlación de los números se puede ver que, en realidad, esas fechas no están cifradas. En realidad sólo están codificadas, parece que en formato de [marca de tiempo UNIX/POSIX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las fechas, observando que son valores numéricos muy próximos los unos con los otros, no aparentan estar cifrados, si no codificados en formato de [marca de tiempo UNIX/POSIX](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix).

Para convertirlos de nuevo en formato de fecha y hora puedes usar la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
SELECT
  TO_TIMESTAMP(
    '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
  ) + NUMTODSINTERVAL(
    fecha,
    'SECOND'
  )
FROM fechas
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5a797b/15